# Find a set of real number that is linearly independent over rational number.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to find a set of 2020 real numbers that is linearly independent over ℚ.

and i know [the sum of n-th root of two to the power of (n-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9vE1.png) are linearly independent over ℚ.

However how to explain it?

Comment: The set {1,pi, pi^2, ... ,pi^2019} is linearly independent over the rationals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $n$ one can find $n$ real numbers linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.Indeed,pick a transcendental $\alpha$ and consider the set $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^{2},..,\alpha^{n-1}\}$.If a non trivial rational combination of this equals zero,then we would have a non constant polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ having $\alpha$ as a root,contradicting the fact that it's transcendental.